# Cannot uninstall SonarQube Community Branch plugin

Tags: sonarqube

I installed a new version of sonarqube-community-branch (from
https://github.com/mc1arke/sonarqube-community-branch-plugin/pull/797

Because it does not work, I want to remove it.
I click the uninstall button in the marketplace and make sure the file in `extensions/plugins/sonarqube-community-branch-plugin-1.16.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` is deleted.

But when I restart SonarQube, it still tries to get the file, the message is
`Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing: ./extensions/plugins/sonarqube-community-branch-plugin-1.16.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.`

**Update:**

sorry, it's my fault. I forgot to modify `conf/sonar.properties` to remove the configuration. It works after I delete the related configurations in sonar.properties.